# expand large data frame in R efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am looking for a solution to expand a large data frame in R into more columns and more rows, given the values of a given column.

Right now I am doing this using a for-loop approach but I am sure there are more crantastic/efficient ways to achieve the same results...

The example will make the question more clear I think.  Let us imagine we have a data frame containing student's information about their grades at three different stages in life.  The student IDs are s1, s2 and s3; and we have measurements of their grades in three different times in their life, m1, m2, and m3; and then at each stage we have a column called more.info with their grades in their courses, encoded as class#topic#grade across all classes taken.

```
library(stringr)
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
example.df = data.frame(measure.id = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m2", "m2", "m3", "m1", "m1", "m3"),
                        student.id = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s2", "s3", "s2"),
                        more.info = c("draw#drawing#4.5;music#singing#5.6;dance#ballet#6.7", "bio#biology#5.6;math#algebra#4.5", "calculus#univariate#6.2; physics#quantum#4.5;chemistry#organic#4.5", 
                                      "bio#biology#5.6;math#algebra#4.5", "bio#biology#3.6;math#algebra#3.5", "calculus#univariate#5.2; physics#quantum#5.2;chemistry#organic#4", "draw#drawing#5;music#singing#5.6;dance#ballet#5.7", 
                                      "draw#drawing#2.5;music#singing#3.6;dance#ballet#4", "calculus#univariate#5.2; physics#quantum#6.5;chemistry#organic#5"))
measure.ids = unique(example.df$measure.id)
```

Then, I'd like to create a new data frame that splits the more.info information and creates a new data frame with more rows and more columns as follows,

```
new.df=data.frame()
splitit <- function(x){
  strsplit(x, '#')
}
for(i in 1:length(measure.ids)){
  measure.id = measure.ids[i]
  tmp = example.df[example.df==measure.id,]
  more.info = tmp$more.info
  more.info = strsplit(more.info,";")
  student.ids = tmp$student.id
  for(j in 1:length(more.info))
  {
    info = more.info[[j]]
    a = sapply(info, splitit)
    b = sapply(a, "[[", 1)
    d = sapply(a, "[[", 2)
    e = sapply(a, "[[", 3)
    new.df = rbind(new.df, 
                   data.frame(measure.id = rep(measure.id, length(info)),
                              student.id = rep(tmp$student.id[j], length(info)),
                              class = b, 
                              topic = d,
                              grade = e)
                   )
  }
}
```

What'd be the most efficient way to achieve this in R?  I am open to apply functions, map/reduce approaches, mclapply for using more cores, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with base functions:

```
# split column by all available separators 
a <- strsplit(example.df$more.info, "; |#|;")
# represent each result as a matrix with 3 columns
a <- lapply(a, function(v) matrix(v, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
# combine all matrixes in one big matrix
aa <- do.call(rbind, a)
# create indices of rows of initial data.frame which corresponds to the created big matrix
b <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(a), function(i) rep(i, nrow(a[[i]]))))
# combine initial data.frame and created big matrix
df <- cbind(example.df[b,], aa)
# remove unnecessary columns and rename remaining ones
df <- df[,-3]
colnames(df)[3:5] <- c("class", "topic", "grade")
```

To increase the speed you may replace all functions of `apply` family in my code with `mclapply`.

I cannot compare the speed since your dataset is very small.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using `data.table`.

Basically, I put the entire data transformation procedure in one line.

```
# Load R package
library(data.table)    

# Convert to data.table object
example.dt <- as.data.table(example.df)

# Transform the data
final.dt <- example.dt[, data.table(do.call(rbind, unlist(lapply(strsplit(x=more.info, split=";"), strsplit, "#"), recursive=FALSE))), by=c("measure.id", "student.id")]

# Rename variables
setnames(final.dt, old=c("V1", "V2", "V3"), new=c("class", "topic", "grade"))


# > final.dt
#     measure.id student.id class   topic grade
#  1:         m1         s1  draw drawing   4.5
#  2:         m1         s1 music singing   5.6
#  3:         m1         s1 dance  ballet   6.7
#  4:         m2         s1 dance drawing   5.6
#  5:         m2         s1  draw  ballet   4.5
#  6:         m3         s1  draw singing   5.6
#  7:         m3         s1 dance drawing   4.5
#  8:         m3         s1 music  ballet   4.5
#  9:         m2         s2 dance drawing   5.6
# 10:         m2         s2  draw  ballet   4.5
# 11:         m2         s3 dance drawing   5.6
# 12:         m2         s3  draw  ballet   4.5
# 13:         m3         s3  draw singing   5.6
# 14:         m3         s3 dance drawing   5.6
# 15:         m3         s3 music  ballet   4.5
# 16:         m1         s2  draw drawing   4.5
# 17:         m1         s2 music singing   5.6
# 18:         m1         s2 dance  ballet   6.7
# 19:         m1         s3  draw drawing   4.5
# 20:         m1         s3 music singing   5.6
# 21:         m1         s3 dance  ballet   6.7
# 22:         m3         s2  draw singing   5.6
# 23:         m3         s2 dance drawing   6.7
# 24:         m3         s2 music  ballet   4.5
#     measure.id student.id class   topic grade
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer has some approaches that might be useful for speeding up your code (e.g `mclapply` and the `data.table` package).

```
require("data.table")
require("parallel")
require("plyr")

#Note the mclapply function.  If you
#are running Mac or Linux, this should be more efficient for you
list.of.dfs <- mclapply(strsplit(example.df$more.info, "; |#|;"),FUN=function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)),mc.cores=1)
combined.df <- rbind.fill(list.of.dfs)


#Use data.table for speed and efficiency.
#example.df <- data.table(cbind(example.df,combined.df))
example.df <- data.table(example.df)
example.df[,paste0(c("class","topic","grade"),
             c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3))):=lapply(combined.df,I)]

#delete unnecessary column
example.df[,more.info:=NULL]


#rbindlist final table (efficient way to rbind)
table1 <- example.df[,list(measure.id,student.id,class=class1,topic=topic1,grade=grade1)]
table2 <- example.df[,list(measure.id,student.id,class=class2,topic=topic2,grade=grade2)]
table3 <- example.df[,list(measure.id,student.id,class=class3,topic=topic3,grade=grade3)]

#final results
final.table <- rbindlist(list(table1,table2,table3))[!is.na(class)]
final.table
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try out two functions that I'm written, [`concat.split.DT`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058) and [`cSplit`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733). Both are presently available as GitHub Gists which can easily be loaded with the "devtools" package.

```
library(devtools)
source_gist(6873058)  # for concat.split.DT
source_gist(11380733) # for cSplit

concat.split.DT(cSplit(example.df, splitCols="more.info", sep=";", direction="long"), 
                splitcols="more.info", sep="#")
#     measure.id student.id more.info_1 more.info_2 more.info_3
#  1:         m1         s1        draw     drawing         4.5
#  2:         m1         s1       music     singing         5.6
#  3:         m1         s1       dance      ballet         6.7
#  4:         m2         s1         bio     biology         5.6
#  5:         m2         s1        math     algebra         4.5
#  6:         m3         s1    calculus  univariate         6.2
#  7:         m3         s1     physics     quantum         4.5
#  8:         m3         s1   chemistry     organic         4.5
#  9:         m2         s2         bio     biology         5.6
# 10:         m2         s2        math     algebra         4.5
# 11:         m2         s3         bio     biology         3.6
# 12:         m2         s3        math     algebra         3.5
# 13:         m3         s3    calculus  univariate         5.2
# 14:         m3         s3     physics     quantum         5.2
# 15:         m3         s3   chemistry     organic         4.0
# 16:         m1         s2        draw     drawing         5.0
# 17:         m1         s2       music     singing         5.6
# 18:         m1         s2       dance      ballet         5.7
# 19:         m1         s3        draw     drawing         2.5
# 20:         m1         s3       music     singing         3.6
# 21:         m1         s3       dance      ballet         4.0
# 22:         m3         s2    calculus  univariate         5.2
# 23:         m3         s2     physics     quantum         6.5
# 24:         m3         s2   chemistry     organic         5.0
#     measure.id student.id more.info_1 more.info_2 more.info_3
```

The column `names` can be easily changed later on with `setnames`.